# How to read file between two patterns Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Hello I'm Try read two patterns in a file **in only line**

example:

bla bla bla **pattern 1 with space** *content content content* **pattern 2 with space** bla bla bla

I'm tried used

```
cat file.asc | awk '/pattern 1 with space/,/pattern 2 with space/'  > test.txt
```

but don't work

I need save two patterns
test.txt:

```
content
content
content
```

Answer (score 0):

same line pattern match needs another approach

```
$ echo "bla bla bla pattern 1 with space content content content pattern 2 with space bla bla bla" |
  sed -E 's/.*pattern 1 with space (.*) pattern 2 with space .*/\1/;s/ /\n/g'
```

content
content
content

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
text="bla bla bla pattern 1 with space content content content pattern 2 with space bla bla bla"
echo "$text" | sed 's/.*pattern 1 with space \(.*\)pattern 2 with space.*/\1/;s/ /\n/g'
```

**output**

```
content
content
content
```